# How to set clang++ as the c++ compiler?

Tags: fedora, c++, alternatives

I'm trying to set clang++ as the system C++ compiler on Fedora 18. I have installed clang and added it to `alternatives` but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ alternatives --display c++
c++ - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/bin/clang++
/usr/bin/clang++ - priority 1
Current `best' version is /usr/bin/clang++.
[user@localhost ~]$ c++ --version
c++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`c++` still appears to be using gcc even though `alternatives` is configured to use clang++.

---

`type -a c++` output:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ type -a c++
c++ is /usr/bin/c++
c++ is /bin/c++
```

Comment: What does `type -a c++` say?

Comment: Added `type -a c++` output to question.

Answer (score 14):

I think that alternatives are the wrong approach here. More generally, I think changing the system default is really the wrong approach. Rather than changing things at that level, I suggest

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

Unless something goes out of its way to break it, this will work with almost all make systems.

If you want this to be the default systemwide, you could put this in the system bash startup scripts in `/etc/`. But, again, I don't think that's a generally good idea. Better to make the choice on a per user — or per-project — basis.